# Python tic tac toe game Winner or not?

Tags: python, list

I'm creating a tic tac toe game in python for a school assignment but can't figure out how to check if theres a winner?

My objective is to create a function that gets called after every turn so the script can check if there is a winner.

This is my script for now, please don't tell the full answer so I can figure it out on my own with some tips and helpful comments :D

```
players = []
markers = ['X', 'O']
game_board = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

def draw_game_board():
    print(" ----------- ")
    print(f"| {game_board[0]} | {game_board[1]} | {game_board[2]} |")
    print(" ----------- ")
    print(f"| {game_board[3]} | {game_board[4]} | {game_board[5]} |")
    print(" ----------- ")
    print(f"| {game_board[6]} | {game_board[7]} | {game_board[8]} |")
    print(" ----------- ")

def main():
    print("*** Welcome to Tic Tac Toe ***")
    name_player1 = input("Fill in the name of player 1: ")
    name_player2 = input("Fill in the name of player 2: ")
    players.append(name_player1)
    players.append(name_player2)
    print("These are the players: ", players)
    print("These are their markers: ", markers) 
    player_turn = 0

    while True:
        player_name = players[player_turn]
        print("\nThe board game looks like this: ")
        draw_game_board()
        player_input = input(f"\n{player_name}, Please choose a number on the board: ")

        if not player_input.isdigit():
            print("ERROR: Selection is not a number.")
            continue

        player_input = int(player_input)

        # Input a valid number
        if 1 < player_input > 9:
            print("ERROR: Number is not between 1 and 9, (1 and 9 included).")
            continue

        # Input a square not taken net
        if not player_input in game_board:
            print("ERROR: number already chosen, choose another one.")
            continue
   
        game_board[player_input - 1] = markers[player_turn]

        # Swap turns after first turn
        if player_turn == 0:
            player_turn = 1
        else:
            player_turn = 0

print(players)
main()
```

I haven't tried anything yet because I can't figure out on how to do it...

Comment: The related questions suggests that there are a few other people bringing their homework to SO - at least one of them has a 'check victory' function that might be worth a look. e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62650984/checking-winner-tic-tac-toe?rq=2

Comment: There are 8 possible ways to win (3 horizontal, 3 vertical, 2 diagonal).  For each of those 8 ways, check if all 3 cells are X (X wins) or if all 3 cells are O (O wins).  There's no more to it than that.  You can encode the 8 sets of cells in a list of lists, with each sub-list being a 3-element list of the cells needed for that win.

Comment: bug: `1 < player_input > 9`

Comment: Thanks but I can't figure out how @TomKarzes I can create 8 if statements but I don't know how because the players are local variables to the main function...

Comment: @Nowie Make a list of lists of the *indexes* of `game_board` you need to check for a win: e.g. `check_lines = [[0,1,2], [0,3,6], [0,4,8]... ]` (there are  *eight* combinations in all). You can then iterate over `check_lines` and test whether all the values are the same: `for x, y, z in check_lines: if game_board[x] == game_board[y] == game_board[z]: ... break`.

Comment: Can't figure it out but how can I post my new code here? It doesn't work because I have to many characters...

What happens now is that it checks by index with 8 if statements and then can return the markers but I need to know who the player is and what player has won but I can't figure it out

Answer (score 0):

> I'm creating a tic tac toe game in python for a school assignment but
> can't figure out how to check if there's a winner?

Just use slicing, eg `game_board[0]`, `game_board[1]`, etc

Remove this:

```
# Input a valid number
if 1 < player_input > 9:
    print("ERROR: Number is not between 1 and 9, (1 and 9 included).")
    continue
```

---

Snippet:

```
    while True:
        player_name = players[player_turn]
        print("\nThe board game looks like this: ")
        draw_game_board()
        player_input = input(f"\n{player_name}, Please choose a number on the board: ")

        if not player_input.isdigit():
            print("ERROR: Selection is not a number.")
            continue

        player_input = int(player_input)

               
        # Input a square not taken net
        if not player_input in game_board:
            print("ERROR: number already chosen, choose another one.")
            continue
   
        game_board[player_input - 1] = markers[player_turn]
        print(f'player_input : {markers[player_turn]}')

        #Winner across
        if game_board[0] == game_board[player_input - 1] and game_board[1] ==game_board[player_input - 1] and game_board[2] ==game_board[player_input - 1]:
            print(f'You WON!')
        elif game_board[3] ==game_board[player_input - 1] and game_board[4] ==game_board[player_input - 1] and game_board[5] ==game_board[player_input - 1]:
            print(f'You WON!')
        if game_board[6] ==game_board[player_input - 1] and game_board[7] ==game_board[player_input - 1] and game_board[8] ==game_board[player_input - 1]:
            print(f'You WON!')

        #Winner column
        if game_board[0] ==game_board[player_input - 1] and game_board[3] ==game_board[player_input - 1] and game_board[6] ==game_board[player_input - 1]:
            print(f'You WON!')
        elif game_board[1] ==game_board[player_input - 1] and game_board[4] ==game_board[player_input - 1] and game_board[7] ==game_board[player_input - 1]:
            print(f'You WON!')
        if game_board[2] ==game_board[player_input - 1] and game_board[5] ==game_board[player_input - 1] and game_board[8] ==game_board[player_input - 1]:
            print(f'You WON!')
            
         
        #Winner diagonal
        if game_board[0] ==game_board[player_input - 1] and game_board[4] ==game_board[player_input - 1] and game_board[8] ==game_board[player_input - 1]:
            print(f'You WON!')
        elif game_board[6] ==game_board[player_input - 1] and game_board[4] ==game_board[player_input - 1] and game_board[2] ==game_board[player_input - 1]:
            print(f'You WON!')
         
        # Input a square not taken net
        if not player_input in game_board:
            print("ERROR: number already chosen, choose another one.")
            continue        

        # Swap turns after first turn
        if player_turn == 0:
            player_turn = 1
        else:
            player_turn = 0

print(players)
main()
```

Output:

```
t, Please choose a number on the board: 9
player_input : X

The board game looks like this: 
 ----------- 
| X | O | X |
 ----------- 
| 4 | 5 | 6 |
 ----------- 
| O | 8 | X |
 ----------- 

r, Please choose a number on the board: 5
player_input : O

The board game looks like this: 
 ----------- 
| X | O | X |
 ----------- 
| 4 | O | 6 |
 ----------- 
| O | 8 | X |
 ----------- 

t, Please choose a number on the board: 6
player_input : X
You WON!

The board game looks like this: 
 ----------- 
| X | O | X |
 ----------- 
| 4 | O | X |
 ----------- 
| O | 8 | X |
 -----------
```